# Magento get language name and language code in template file

Tags: php, magento-1.9

Magento get language name and language code 
[(see screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9som3.png)
in template file to generate this code:

```
<div class="gb">EN</div>
```

All code:

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>

<div class="gb">EN</div>

<ul class='dropdown-menu'>
 <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>

    <li>
        <div class="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getCode()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?></div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Thank You

Answer (score -2):

Code:

```
<div class="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape(Mage::app()
->getStore()->getName()) ?></div>
```

All code:

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>

<div class="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape(Mage::app()
->getStore()->getName()) ?></div>

<ul class='dropdown-menu'>
<?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>

<li>
    <div class="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getCode()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?></div>
</li>
```